# Ubuntu 16.04 slow

Tags: drivers, 16.04, cpu

I've recently made the switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit), but I've begun noticing that a lot of things are running a lot slower.

A few examples:

- Fast-forwarding video files (using VLC) makes the video stagger and/or even crash VLC
- Unpacking .zip/.rar files goes really slow as well

My computer has:

- 128 GB SSD drive with Ubuntu as the sole OS running on it
- 8 GB of RAM
- Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM
- Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz (8 cores in total with Hyper-threading)

I'm at a loss here and I really don't want to switch back to Windows, but the speed differences are really too noticeable. Could someone please advise me on this matter?

Comment: Do you have 2 AMD cards inside it, or am I missing something? With Nvidia that will work just fine with closed driver, not sure about how AMD handles that. Maybe if the older card uses an older driver and the newer one can run on AMDGPU that does something weird.

Comment: It is just the standard card that was already inside of my computer when I acquired it and I do not have a second card inside it.

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` and the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to install drivers for your video card. Use the "Additional Drivers" application.

Found this link : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: Thank you for the response. The "Additional Drivers" app says:

"Unknown:Unknown"

"This device is using an alternate driver"

and then it shows the following selected:
"Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)"

I can't install anything else (to my knowledge).

Comment: sorry, my personal case was with nVidia. I can't help you much with your AMD.

Comment: Ah, thanks anyway! I appreciate you taking the time.